# How to implement previous/next pagination in azure cosmos db for asp.net core web api

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I need to support pagination for azure cosmos db. I know that cosmos db works on continuation token for next set of result. However I don't understand how to navigate to previous set of result.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your question is too general but you can take a look at how I've done that for Cosmonaut: https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut#pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i know,from official way,you could only implement pagination based on continuation token.You need to encapsulate method to achieve that.

You could refer to the [document](https://medium.com/@nick.chapsas/cosmosdb-fluent-pagination-with-cosmonaut-4806f67c26cf) wrote by @Nick.
Also,you could refer to below sample code:

```cs
    private static async Task<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<CeleryTask>>> QueryDocumentsByPage(int pageNumber, int pageSize, string continuationToken)
    {
        DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri("https://{CosmosDB/SQL Account Name}.documents.azure.com:443/"), "{CosmosDB/SQL Account Key}");

        var feedOptions = new FeedOptions {
            MaxItemCount = pageSize,
            EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,

            // IMPORTANT: Set the continuation token (NULL for the first ever request/page)
            RequestContinuation = continuationToken 
        };

        IQueryable<CeleryTask> filter = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<CeleryTask>("dbs/{Database Name}/colls/{Collection Name}", feedOptions);
        IDocumentQuery<CeleryTask> query = filter.AsDocumentQuery();

        FeedResponse<CeleryTask> feedRespose = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<CeleryTask>();

        List<CeleryTask> documents = new List<CeleryTask>();
        foreach (CeleryTask t in feedRespose)
        {
            documents.Add(t);
        }

        // IMPORTANT: Ensure the continuation token is kept for the next requests
        return new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<CeleryTask>>(feedRespose.ResponseContinuation, documents);
    }
```

Then, the following example illustrates how to retrieve documents for a given page by calling the previous method:

```cs
    private static async Task QueryPageByPage()
    {
        // Number of documents per page
        const int PAGE_SIZE = 3;

        int currentPageNumber = 1;
        int documentNumber = 1;

        // Continuation token for subsequent queries (NULL for the very first request/page)
        string continuationToken = null;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"----- PAGE {currentPageNumber} -----");

            // Loads ALL documents for the current page
            KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<CeleryTask>> currentPage = await QueryDocumentsByPage(currentPageNumber, PAGE_SIZE, continuationToken);

            foreach (CeleryTask celeryTask in currentPage.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[{documentNumber}] {celeryTask.Id}");
                documentNumber++;
            }

            // Ensure the continuation token is kept for the next page query execution
            continuationToken = currentPage.Key;
            currentPageNumber++;
        } while (continuationToken != null);

        Console.WriteLine("\n--- END: Finished Querying ALL Dcuments ---");
    }
```

BTW,you could follow below traces about this feature in cosmos db feedback:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/377
- https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6350987--documentdb-allow-paging-skip-take